# In javascript w2ui, is there a comprehensive list of all icons available?

Tags: javascript, icons, w2ui

I don't see a list of what is available so I can't really go beyond w2ui's demos.

Answer (score 1):

w2ui only has a very limited set of icons.

You can find them here: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/blob/master/src/less/icons/icon-font.css
and here: https://github.com/vitmalina/w2ui/blob/master/src/less/w2ui.less

If you need more icons you should use font-awesome or any other web-font - or you can simply use images for your custom icons.